# Trouble with join statement for selecting data across tables with MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to display events that a user has created and events that he has signed up for. I have three tables for this.

```
//events
| event_id | event_title  | event_details   | event_timestamp | userid
    1           title1        test              1234              1
    2           title2         testing2         123               2


//registration_items : event_id references events.event_id
| id | event_id | task_name 
   1       2        task 1

//registration_signup : id references registration_items.id
| id  | userid | timestamp 
   1       1        1234
```

Here's the current query I have. **Right now it only displays the event the user created. It should display both created events and ones he signed up for**

```
select events.*, registration_items.*, registration_signup.*, users.username from events
INNER JOIN users on users.userid = events.userid
LEFT JOIN registration_items ON registration_items.event_id = events.event_id
LEFT JOIN registration_signup ON registration_signup.id = registration_items.id
WHERE events.userid = '$user_id' OR registration_signup.userid = '$user_id' ORDER BY events.event_timestamp DESC
```

For userid1 the output should be

```
Title
title1  (the user created this)
title2  (the user signed up for this)
```

For userid2 the output should be

```
Title
title2
```

Comment: Can you please show what are your expected results based on the sample data above?

Comment: According to your events table User id is 1, 2 for both title and title2..is that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select events.*, registration_items.*, registration_signup.*, users.username
from events
  INNER JOIN users on users.userid = events.userid
  LEFT JOIN registration_items ON registration_items.event_id = events.event_id
  LEFT JOIN registration_signup ON registration_signup.id = registration_items.id
WHERE registration_signup.userid = '$user_id'

union

select events.*, registration_items.*, registration_signup.*, users.username
from events
  INNER JOIN users on users.userid = events.userid
  INNER JOIN registration_items ON registration_items.event_id = events.event_id
  INNER JOIN registration_signup ON registration_signup.id = registration_items.id
WHERE events.userid = '$user_id'

ORDER BY events.event_timestamp DESC
```

Comment: Hmm, this is acting very strange. When I run it in phpmyadmin it says "unknown table registration_items" but I can type "select * from registration_items" and the contents of the the table will display without an error.

Comment: My bad.  Answer edited.  I forgot you needed to join to registration_items, and registration_signup because you use them in your select statement.  Answer edited.

Comment: Thanks, got it to work. I had a typo at first. Anyway, your method works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it's correct to guess that you have a typo in the sample data. Because your query works the moment you change the user id to 1 for both events, signed up events.. So please take a look at this reference demo and comment if it's not a typo...

- ### [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f892/2)

query: (your query..)

```
select u.userid,e.event_id as id,  
ri.event_id as evt, e.event_title, 
ri.task_name,
rs.timestamp, 
u.name from events e
INNER JOIN users u on 
u.userid = e.userid
LEFT JOIN registration_items ri ON 
ri.event_id = e.event_id
LEFT JOIN registration_signup rs ON 
rs.id = ri.id
WHERE e.userid = '1' or
rs.userid = '1' 
ORDER BY e.event_timestamp DESC
;
```

Results:

```
| USERID | ID | EVT | EVENT_TITLE | TASK_NAME | TIMESTAMP | NAME |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|      1 |  1 |   1 |      title1 |    task 1 |      1234 | john |
|      1 |  2 |   2 |      title2 |  task 1.2 |      3456 | john |
```

Comment: I was getting a whole bunch of "unkown field" errors. Everything from the userid to events.event_id

Comment: Definitely you will because I have changed username to username I suppose.. But the most important thing that you need to clarify is if that was a typo... because if it isn't a typo my query is not the answer I am afraid.. :$